# How to install Steam on Elementary OS Loki 64-bit

Tags: software-installation, elementary-os, steam

I have a problem with Steam client on Elementary OS Loki 64-bit.

It won't run, output from terminal when running `steam` follows:

> ```
> Running Steam on elementary 0.4 64-bit
> STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
> Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
> libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
> libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we download the latest Steam package:

```
wget --continue http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/archive/precise/steam_latest.deb
```

Then we update `apt` cache:

```
sudo apt update
```

And install the Steam package with `apt`:

```
sudo apt install ./steam_latest.deb
```

After you first run Steam and agree to EULA, it will check for additional packages needed:

> ```
> Steam needs to install these additional packages:
> ```

[image: Steam needs to install these additional packages:]

You enter your `sudo` password and agree with the installation and wait for it to install.

Open terminal again and delete these two files:

```
rm $HOME/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1

rm $HOME/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Run Steam again, this time it will start with:

> ```
> Updating Steam...
> ```

Once successfully updated you will need to remove those two files again.

Now you are done, you may launch Steam and log into your account.

I'm afraid you will have to repeat those two files deletion once the Steam client gets updated again, until they fix it, at least.